# Incompatible type compile error

Tags: java

link for my code error [image]

> Incompatible type found java.util.vector required HighRights.
>   Sorry I am new to Java and I just don't understand how to do this question

Notice: in this exercises we will NOT use Generics

In the following program, the code in the method `CountHighs` is missing. 
Write the code for this method, which takes as argument the vector m  and 
returns the number of objects in the vector that are instances of `HighRights`

The method should also:
- check that the elements extracted from the vector are indeed instances 
  of the classes `HighRights` or `LowRights`. If an element is not an instance of such classes, 
  then the method should return -1.

- handle the `NullPointerException` in case the vector is null. Use the following 
  code when catching the occurring exception:

  ```
  System.out.println("Error");
  System.exit(0);
  return 0;
  ```

(Hint:

1. use `m.size()` to get the number of elements in the vector m
2. use the keyword `instanceof` to check if an object is an instance of a class)

For example,

- if the vector m contains only two `HighRights` objects and one `LowRights` objects then `CountHighs(m)` will return 2
- if the vector m contains only two `HighRights` objects and one `String` objects then `CountHighs(m)` will return -1
- if the vector m contains only five `LowRights` objects no `HighRights` objects then `CountHighs(m)` will return 0

Any help/tips will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is unreadable sorry. Would you mind posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You should post full code (not as image) and the error stack trace, but I think I know the problem. You have a `public static int CountHighs(Vector m)` method, and inside it you check condition `m instanceof HighRights/LowRights` - it's never true, a Vector is a Vector, not HighRights. You need to check if *objects stored in the vector* are HighRights or LowRights. To do this, you should use a loop:

```
for(Object obj : m){ //it will iterate over the vector `m`, with each iteration `obj` will be the next element
    if(obj instanceof HighRights){
        ++countHighRights;
    }
    else if(obj instanceof LowRights){
        //do nothing - you should only count HighRights
    }
    else{ //obj is neither HighRight nor LowRight
        return -1;
    }
}
```